# Show in a ListView a TextView and an Image from Firebase

Tags: android, image, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have in my Database this: [image]

I want to display all the data into a ListView, I have no errors but is not showing me the text and the image. I have a ModelClass:

```
public class ModelClass {
String title,image;

public ModelClass(String title,String image) {
    this.image = image;
    this.title = title;
}

public ModelClass() {
}

public String getTitle() {return title;   }
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}}
```

An Adaptor:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ModelClass> {
private Activity context;
private int resource;
private List<ModelClass> listImage;

public MyAdapter(@NonNull Activity context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<ModelClass> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    listImage = objects;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    View v = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
    TextView tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_desert);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_desert);

    tvName.setText(listImage.get(position).getTitle());
    Glide.with(context).load(listImage.get(position).getImage()).into(img);

    return v;

}}
```

And the class where is the ListView:

```
public class Deserturi extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private List<ModelClass> imgList;
private ListView lv;
private MyAdapter myAdapter;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_deserturi);

   imgList = new ArrayList<>();
   lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.blog_list);

   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
   progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait loading list image...");
   progressDialog.show();

   mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data");

   mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           progressDialog.dismiss();


           for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

               ModelClass img = snapshot.getValue(ModelClass.class);
               imgList.add(img);
           }


           myAdapter = new MyAdapter(Deserturi.this, R.layout.design_row, imgList);

           lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

           progressDialog.dismiss();
       }
   });
```

Can you please tell me what I did wrong?! Thanks

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your activity:

```
...
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(Deserturi.this, R.layout.design_row, imgList);
lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       progressDialog.dismiss();

       for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

           ModelClass img = snapshot.getValue(ModelClass.class);
           myAdapter.addElement(img);
       }

       myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

In your adapter:

```
public void addElement(ModelClass element) {

    listImage.add(element);
}
```

And in your model:

```
public class ModelClass {
String Nume,imagine;
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!!

Comment: Consider accepting this answer so that other users know it has been solved.